# Socket returns false after S3 / resume in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I am using the following C# code.

When I do Sleep my computer and resume it again then Socket becomes null.

```
private Socket m_sock = null;
```

I am checking Socket through the following code.

```
if (m_sock == null) { return false; }
```

But it's very rare that I got false. I haven't got false all the time after Sleep/resume my computer. It returns false may be after 100(00) or more cycle.

So, here is more Code

```
internal virtual bool IsOpen 
{
    get
    {
        //If the socket equals null there is not a connection
        if (m_sock == null) { return false; }

        //return the sockets connected property
        return m_sock.Connected;
    }
}
```

m_sock = null at 3 possibly known places :)

1.

```
//If there is a socket object release it
if (m_sock != null) { m_sock = null; }
```

2.

```
   private void CloseSocket()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (m_sock == null) return;
            if (m_sock.Connected)
            {
                m_sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            m_sock.Close();
            m_sock = null;

        }
    }
```

3.

```
    //Check that there not already exists an open connection
    if (!IsOpen)
    {                
        //If there is a socket object release it
        if (m_sock != null) { m_sock = null; }
 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I find this hard to believe. I would be entirely unsurprised at it being disconnected - but I would be *extremely* surprised at the variable being trashed. I think it's much more likely to be a bug (possibly a race condition) elsewhere.

Comment: Since we don't know anything else about your code (including if your code explicitly sets the socket to null someplace), there's probably not much we can do to help.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Quite agree with you. but it's hard to find race condition. any idea?

Comment: @NateC-K: I have edited more code into above post.

Comment: @Khokhar: You've edited *bits* of the code into the post, but not a coherent whole, nor anything which shows where you're detecting it becoming null. For example, `IsOpen` could easily start returning false when you come back from sleep, without the variable becoming null.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me why this is tagged "embedded"

Comment: Thanks for your time and cooperation. Problem was somewhere else. This was actually Firmware and driver's problem, which causes to some unknown errors.

Comment: @Clifford: I suppose that embedded means “embedded system programming”.

Comment: @Khokhar:  I know what "embedded" means (check my profile!); that is not what is unclear to me.  My point was rather that the question makes no reference to that, and even if it is on an embedded system, the question is not about or particular to embedded systems.  Moreover although C# can be used on .NET Micro, WinCE, and Windows XP/7 Embedded, it is not particularly prevalent in embedded systems development.  The tag pulls in an audience that probably brings little to the probability or quality of an answer.